# How to use conditional arguments while plotting in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe of which two columns are of date and sales. date column varies from 2012-10-22 to 2016-09-22. I want to plot the graph of sales in jan 2013 by day without creating any subset.

I have used this-
ggplot(subsales,aes(Date,spdby))+geom_line()

Is it possible by using ggplot()?

[I have plotted the sales per day and look like this-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy4Ps.png)

I want to zoom in, to January 2013 and want to extract that part as a new plot.

Comment: Yes it is! Try `scale_x_date()` or `xlim()`!

Comment: but, I want to plot only dates of jan 2013 from the span of 5.5 years

Comment: Then use different alpha values, eg. 0 and 1. It would be much more easier to help if you add a small reproducible example to your question

Answer (score 0):

yes, in ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

subsales <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2017-1-1"), by = "day"),
  spdby = runif(1462, 2000, 6000)
)

ggplot(subsales, aes(date, spdby)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(subsales, aes(date, spdby)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2013-1-1"), as.Date("2013-1-31")))
#> Warning: Removed 1431 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the plots to be side-by-side or only plot the subset of data for the time range you specified in your post?

Comment: how to find the local peaks and valleys for the above data?